# Why after the UPDATE operation in PostgreSQL the row goes to the last place?

Tags: postgresql, rdbms

I had this question on the job interview in some smell company. Now I understand that it's a wrong question itself.

My suggestion was that the PostgreSQL is copying the row and then deleting the previous one, i.e. using transaction, and then sorting rows by system hidden index.

They said that it's not a right answer, but they didn't say the right answer anyway because the interview was like a ping-pong with a high speed in one direction.

I've asked guys from core-team who make PostgreSQL in IRC. They said that the result order could be unpredictable and gave me documentation of PostgreSQL in very low-level in C so I didn't understand anything.

Now I found this statement https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html :

> If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the returned rows are sorted in
> the specified order. If ORDER BY is not given, the rows are returned
> in whatever order the system finds fastest to produce. (See ORDER BY
> Clause below.)

Okay, but what if we use very simple table without any relations in the scheme, like
USER (id, name). What the point is there? Why the updated row would be on the last place? What should I answer on the interview?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, not only PostgreSQL, but all other databases, the order of tuples isn't guaranteed. When you do insertion, each tuple is been written to page in PostgreSQL. Then, the page will be written into the disk and following the corresponding file system mechanism. The newly updated row isn't necessary to be the last place, unless the ORDER BY is specified. The reason the newly updated row appear at the last place, that might be the fact of LRU replacement policy is been adopted in that file system.

Comment: Yes, I think *LRU* scheme is about that. Similar questions here has only the answer like "it's not obligatory to return the sorted data for RDBMS".

I've found this presentation where they describe a transition from *LRU* to *Clock Sweep* scheme: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Inside-the-PostgreSQL-Shared-Buffer-Cache.pdf